# Localhost page can't be accessed from some ip's and proxies

Tags: apache, ip, localhost

I have apache installed listening to 8888, and port 8888 oppened, due the fact that 80 and 8080 are blocked by my ISP. I have no firewalls running.

The page hosted on my computer, works from some proxies like http://www.webproxyonline.info/ for example, but doesnt work from some others, like zend2.com.

I also tested to access the page from 2 dedicated servers that I own, but without success. I can ping my computer IP, but when I type wget myip:8888 i get nothing.

I also tried to run the code file_get_contents('http://myip:8888'); but no success too.

What can be causing this problem?

thanks.

**UPDATED: PROBLEM SOLVED.**

The problem is that the firewall CSF on my dedicated server was blocking outgoing traffic to my ip.... I just added my ip to the alloed list...

Comment: If 443 port is not blocked you can serve https.

Answer (score 0):

Um, if you're actually binding localhost (that is, 127.0.0.1), then it *shouldn't* be accessible from other machines. That's how localhost works. You need to bind a actual external IP address for your machine.

Comment: Or bind to `0.0.0.0`, which is IP agnostic (should work if you have  multiple IP addresses).

Comment: of course i'm trying to reach it by the external ip. As I said before. On some proxyes it works.